# How to distribute C++ application which calls Python?

Tags: python, c++

I know there is some way to call Python from C++, like Python/C API or Boost.Python.  My question is, how can I distribute the application?  For example, does user still need to install Python and Python packages on their machine?

My user case is:  I want to use some Python code from my C++ code. The main application is written in C++.  Then I am going to deploy my app. The goal is to make the app self contained, and user don't need to install Python and Python packages at all.

The possible steps may be :
1, calling Python from C++ via Python/C API or boost.Python from source code.
2, bring Python/C libraries  together with application.

I hope after these 2 steps, my app will be a self-contained and standalone software.  User can just copy the app folder to any other machines which has no Python installed.

Note that due to license issue, I can not use PyInstaller. I also meet some problems when trying to use "Nuitka" to make the Python part self contained.  So I am now trying directly calling Python from C++.  I know it will run on my developer machine. But needs to confirm that this solution can also make app self-contained and  won't ask user to install Python.

Update:  Now I feel I need to do something to make my app self-contained if I use Python/C to call python from C++ :
1, I need to bring all needed runtime with my app. (C++ runtime of course, and the python_version.dll)
2, I need to deploy a Python interpreter inside my app.  Simply copy the Python folder from Python installation and remove some not needed files (like header files, lib files)
3, use Py_SetPythonHome function to points to the copied Python interpreter inside the app.

Comment: The Python C/C++ API's primary focus is on writing Python modules. Therefore, it is designed to be invoked from Python, not the other way around. I think you'd have a fair amount of trouble with that.

Comment: @ifconfig that's the reverse of OP's usecase. OP is calling Python from C++, your links are about calling C++ from Python.

Comment: Ah okay, removed.

Comment: I believe docker is what you are looking for.

Comment: Have a look at PyInstaller. It bundles up a python app into an executable for Windows, Mac, or Linux. I believe it assumes that the entrypoint will be a Python script, but there may be a way to use a C++ entrypoint. If not, wrap your C++ code into a Python module and call it from Python. https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not ask the user to install the correct version of Python. That becomes a tech support nightmare. Definitely bundle your own Python interpreter unless you're distributing via a Linux package manager.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're on the right track. Basically, you should obtain a Python (shared or static) library, compile your program with it, and of course bundle the Python dependencies you have with your program. The best documentation I've read is available here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html#embedding-python-in-another-application. Roughly, the process is:

1. Get a Python library from python.org and compile with `./configure --enable-shared` (I believe omitting `--enable-shared` does only produce the `python` binary).
2. Compile your program. Have it reference the headers under `Include` and link the library. Note that you can obtain the compiler and linker flags you need as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems).
3. Call Python code from within your application using e.g. `PyRun_SimpleString()` or other functions from the C API. Note that you may also depend on the Python standard library (under `Lib` in the distribution) if there's any functionality you use from it.

If you linked against Python statically, at this point you're done, aside from bundling any Python code you depend on, which I'm not sure is relevant in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering from the same problem, I had a project which is made up of **C++** and **python**(embedded) and there is a problem of deployment/distribution.
After research, I got a solution which is not perfect (means it will be helpful to run your app in other system)

> - change visual studio in release mode and compile(you got a folder in your working directory)
> - install pyinstaller (pip install pyinstaller)
> - then navigate to pyinstaller folder and command:-pyinstaller.exe "your script_file_path.py"
>   -it will create a **dist** folder
> - copy that folder in working folder where exe exists.

remember.
dist folder and c/python code compiled by same version of python.

now good to go.
it will work.