# How to embed python into C++ aplication and then deploy/release?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment, release

I am currently working on a C++ gui application. The application uses the Python/C API to call some python scripts. The scripts are located in the solution directory, and I call them by simply providing the path. This is currently working fine while debugging the application or even running the generated .exe file, but I am wondering how this could work if I want to release and distribute the application onto a different computer for someone to use. How can these scripts be deployed with the application?

I also have a .ttf font file with the same situation. How can this resource file be deployed with the application?

In other words, I want to deploy/release a C++ application with the scripts and resource files.

FYI: the C++ application is a Visual Studio project.

Thanks for the help in advance, and let me know if any more information is needed!

Update:

I just wanted to clear up the way my project is working currently:

```
PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(5); // I setup the arguments the python function needs
PyImport_ImportModule("requests"); // imports...
// make python call
PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

So this is (for the most part) how I call the scripts with the C++ source code. The scripts are located in a folder that is located in the solution directory.

I hope this explains my problem a little better.

Update:

Just another little update... Using some answers to other similar questions got me to the following point:

I need to obtain a python library, compile and link it with my C++ application, and then bundle the dependencies with the application ([How to distribute C++ application which calls Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651487/how-to-distribute-c-application-which-calls-python))

So I guess my question is now shifting to how I would be able to get this done. What are the specific steps to do this? I also got a link (https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) to an embedded distribution of a python environment (maybe this should somehow be used?). Also, I am able to statically link python into the application. I just don't know how to bundle and deploy the scripts I created and use in the application.

Comment: if youre looking for a py->exe converter, pyinstaller works. You can then just implement an argparser related module to call your exe from your c++ file.

Comment: Are you looking for a software *installer*?

Comment: I don't have a problem running the scripts with C++ source code (that's what the API is for). I'm just unsure how the scripts can be packed with the application if I want to deploy/release the application.

Comment: Are you using an absolute path or a relative path?

Comment: I am using absolute paths.

Comment: Try to use relative path.

Comment: Is your problem solved? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi @levente.nas, did you solve your issue? If yes, how? I am doing a c++ app that connects to a server in python and does some ML with the input from c++. I need to ensure to call the server before running the GUI, so I was thinking to import the module into c++. I don't want to distribute the script source code as well. What did you do?

Comment: Hi @thecatbehindthemask! I'm still working on it, but what seems to work for me is downloading the embeddable python zip from the link in my question. From here I put the extracted contents of the zip in my project directory and it seems to find the python dll when running the application in distribution solution configuration. I still need to add all the scripts and external python libraries that it depends on in the application.

Comment: @levente.nas thank you for the answer! How do you generate the python DLL from the source code? so, are you able to load the .pyd file using the PyImport_ImportModule function from the Python C API?

Comment: Hi @thecatbehindthemask! So far all I've done is add the embeddable python to my source directory. I haven't been able to test whether or not the Python C api works at all. I'm having some issues with the gui library I'm using in the distribution solution configuration. What I do know is that I'm not getting "python dll not found" errors and that my application runs fine in debug mode using the python installed on my system. Once I get to testing the python c api, I'll provide an answer to this question. :)

Comment: I see, thank you so much! @levente.nas . I will provide you an answer if I arrive before to this point, I already integrated the Python C API in the client. I miss generating the DLL. I think this need to be done with Cython. shorturl.at/dqDT2 "A .pyx or .py file is compiled by Cython to a .c file, containing the code of a Python extension module. The .c file is compiled by a C compiler to a .so file (or .pyd on Windows) which can be import-ed directly into a Python session. setuptools takes care of this part. Although Cython can call them for you in certain cases"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PyImport_ImportModule("requests")
```

The parameter is "requests".
Put the py file aside exe file when distributing.

Comment: Do I need to do this with all the python libraries the application uses?

Comment: Libraries usually also need to be placed in the same directory as exe or in the system environment path.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to make sure that the C++ application can still access the python libraries when its released and those libraries/dependencies arent necessarily available on other systems.

You'll need to, like another commenter suggested, use one of the importing modules utilities, like PyImport_ImportModule("library name").

You can see these utilities here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html

You'll also need to either

1. Put the libraries that you want with the exe (in the same directory) or
2. put them in the system environment path ( which is probably less straightforward).

Hope that helps and that I understood you're question correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. Thank you!